# is there 3ds max like sweep functionality in Blender?

Tags: modeling

can I do something like this in Blender (link below)? 3ds max has an awesome sweep modifier. The curve bevel option in Blender is not good enough for such results, neither the array modifier + curve modifier, because in Max you can control the bank angle.
https://youtu.be/0FxEPymScO8

Comment: could you please describe the kind of object you'd like to create and why the curve bevel is limited according to you? I don't see the difference...

Comment: You can modifiy the roll of each vertex of the curve, is this what banking refers to ?